# TypeError: jasmine.addMatchers is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am using "jasmine":"^2.5.2" and in node, I get error:

```
 TypeError: jasmine.addMatchers is not a function
```

when using `jasmine-node spec`from terminal running a simple example as below.

What could cause this issue and how to fix it?

```
   function helloWorld() {
      return "Hello world!";
    }

    describe('keyframes-tool', function () {
        it("says hello", function() {
            expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I got the same issue with jasmine-node 1.14.5..no clue whats causing this

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably thrown by an incompatible `jasmine-promise-matchers` library.

Adding the promise matchers differs between jasmine versions 1 and 2 (and the check of an older version of the promise matcher library fails for jasmine 3).

It should be fixed by updating to a sufficiently new version compatible with the `jasmine-core` version used (e.g. at least `2.6.0` for version 3 or greater).